# Javascript function that checks whether number is palindrome

Tags: javascript

I read through a few of palindrome questions posted here, but unfortunately couldn't find a way to fix mine. An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Input: 989
Output: "It's a palindrome"

Input: 23
Output: "Not a palindrome"

Input: 9 
Output: "It's a palindome" (any single digit)
```

My try

```
function Palindrome(num) { 

  let numToStringArray = num.toString().split('');
  let reversedArray = numToStringArray.reverse();


  if (num.toString().length<2) {
     return "It's a palindrome"
  }
  else { 
        for (let i = 0; i<numToStringArray; i++;) {    
           if (numToStringArray[i] !== reversedArray[i]) {
             return "It's not a palindrome"
             }
            else {
                 return "It's a palindrome"
                 }
             }
        } 
}
```

When invoked, the function only works for single-digit strings. I tried to fix my for-loop, as I feel that the problem lies in the following line:

```
 if (numToStringArray[i] !== reversedArray[i])
```

but could not come up with a working solution. Thanks for reading or even helping me out!

Comment: `i<numToStringArray;` - `numToStringArray` is an array of strings (characters). You want its `.length`

Comment: `return` stops the execution of the function, you might want to think about that too.

Comment: Even after fixing the loop test, there is another logical error.  You want the positive return only after you've checked for *all* the possible negative ones.  If you remove `return "It's a palindrome"` from the `else` clause and put it after the loop has finished, it should work.  But as other answers show, there are better ways of writing this code.

Comment: Also note that there is a very strong convention in JS that function names are only capitalized if they're constructor functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm spotting several problems...

First, you don't want a `;` after your `i++` in the loop definition.  In jsFiddle at least, that's resulting in a syntax error.  Other environments may be more forgiving, but it's worth fixing.

Second, the loop condition is wrong:

```
i < numToStringArray
```

should be:

```
i < numToStringArray.length
```

Third, the logic of the loop is a bit broken.  You're returning "It's a palindrome" immediately if the *very first pair* match.  So by that logic "1231" is a palindrome.  Instead, only return within the loop if you find that it's *not* a palindrome.  If the loop completes without returning, then return that it's a palindrome:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numToStringArray.length; i++) {
    if (numToStringArray[i] !== reversedArray[i]) {
        return "It's not a palindrome";
    }
}
return "It's a palindrome";
```

Comment: @ David, thanks for your thorough answer, I really understood where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Made this quick & working solution:

```js
function checkPalindrome(num) {
    var numString = num.toString();
    return numString.split("").reverse().join("") == numString;
}
```

Provide an integer parameter inside the `checkPalindrome()` function, and it will return either `true` or `false`.

For example:

```js
if (checkPalindrome(123321)) {
    console.log("Is a palindrome");
} else {
    console.log("Not a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: Please:  `return numString.split("").reverse().join("") === numString`

Comment: Also your example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @mplungjan: note, though, that no type coercion is possible.  While it is arguably a good habit to always use `===` over `==`, it can make no difference here.

Comment: Even better reason to use it here

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
str === str.split('').reverse().join("")
```

like so

```js
const palindrome = num => {
  const str = num.toString();
  return `It's ${str.length<2 || str === str.split('').reverse().join("") ? "" : "not "}a palindrome`
};

console.log(
  [989, 23, 9].map(num => `${num}: ${palindrome(num)}`)
)
```

Comment: Why retain that initial `if` block and the double call to `num.toString()`?  And why no declaration for `str`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet must have been needing coffee. I cannot test my mod is n mobile but it should be better now

Answer (score 0):

actually your numToStringArray is not reversing. Try this:

```
function Palindrome(num) { 
      
      let numToStringArray = num.toString().split('');
      let reversedArray = num.toString().split('').reverse();
    
    console.log("here", numToStringArray, reversedArray)
      if (num.toString().length<2) {
         return "It's a palindrome"
      }
      else { 
            for (let i = 0; i<numToStringArray.length; i++) {    
               if (numToStringArray[i] !== reversedArray[i]) {
                 return "It's not a palindrome"
                 }
                else {
                     return "It's a palindrome"
                     }
                 }
            } 
    }
    
    console.log(Palindrome(686))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Also no need for else after a return

Answer (score 0):

The reason your logic doesn't is mainly due to the fact that you use `i < numToStringArray` instead of `i < numToStringArray.length` as mentioned in the comments.

The simplest way to achieve what you want though, would simply be-

```js
function isPalindrome(num) { 
  return num === Number(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of its function, something you could do after using the split method and the reverse method to read the number from right to left, is to use the join to transform it into a string again and then compare them, like this:

```js
function Palindrome(num) { 

  let numToStringArray = num.toString().split('');
  let reversedArray = numToStringArray.reverse().join('');
  
  if (num.toString() == reversedArray)
    console.log('It\'s a palindrome');
  else
    console.log('It\'s not a palindrome');
  
}

Palindrome(9);
Palindrome(232);
Palindrome(152);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
const pal = num => {
  let reversedNum =  parseFloat(num.toString().split('').reverse().join(''));
  if (reversedNum === num) {
    console.log("palindrome")
  } else {
    console.log("no palindrome")
  }
}

pal(12121);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `split`, `reverse` and `join`, it can be checked through a single array.

```js
function Palindrome(num) {

    let numToStringArray = num.toString();

    var len = numToStringArray.length;

    if (len < 2) {
        return "It's a palindrome"
    }
    else {

        for (var i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
            if (numToStringArray[i] !== numToStringArray[len - 1 - i]) {
                return "It's not a palindrome";
            }

            return "It's a palindrome"
        }
    }

}

console.log(Palindrome(989));
console.log(Palindrome(23));
console.log(Palindrome(9));
```

Answer (score 0):

A short function to test if the number is a Palindrome and returns a "true" or "false" is as follows:

You can then call it and output your text result "It's a palindrome" in case it returns true or "Not a palindrome" if returns false.

Test examples provided below.

```js
const IsPalindrome = e => (e+="").split("").reverse().join("") == e;

// ======== test =============
console.log(IsPalindrome(23));     // false
console.log(IsPalindrome(121));    // true
console.log(IsPalindrome(9889));   // true
console.log(IsPalindrome(989));    // true
console.log(IsPalindrome(1));      // true
```

Comment: Not loving the type coercion with `number+=""`, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

To meet your specific requirements for the output text. Here is a one-liner function based on the function below:

```js
function IsPalindrome(n) {
 return n + (((n+="").split("").reverse().join("") == n) ?  " is a palindrome" : " is not a palindrome");
}

// ======== test =============
console.log(IsPalindrome(23));     // 23 is not a palindrome
console.log(IsPalindrome(121));    // 121 is a palindrome
console.log(IsPalindrome(9889));   // 9889 is a palindrome
console.log(IsPalindrome(989));    // 989 is a palindrome
console.log(IsPalindrome(1));      // 1 is a palindrome
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let a, b = 121;
a = b;

console.log(String(b).split("").reverse().join() === String(a).split("").join());
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.